# 'option/alt' keyboard characters replaced with â€™

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to use option/alt characters in HTML, but it is replaced with â€™. If I try to set innerHTML to **Isn't this so nice? • It's so nice!**, it might turn out to be **Isnâ€™t this so nice â€™ Itâ€™s so nice!** I have no idea why it does this, and replaces the apostrophes and bullets (option + 8) with **â€™**, and I would provide an example but it's not being replaced here on StackOverflow's snippets. Please me how to fix this problem if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to escape the characters such as the apostrophe `'` as `&rsqo;`. Look up HTML escape characters.

HTML is unable to render certain characters if they are not escaped. For example if I wanted to say
<p> 5 > 2 </p>,

HTML would be confused about the angle bracket between 5 and 2. Instead, the content should be written

```
<p> 5 &gt; 2 </p>
```